# Fill dataframe cells entry using dataframe column names and index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I try to fill a datafame using following approach:

- I generate a `mxn` size dataframe
- Column names for the dataframe are`A to N` and are read from a list passed to the method.
- define the index for the dataframe.
- fill the dataframe entries with Column name + _ + index

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

def generate_data(N_rows, N_cols,names_df =[]):
    if N_rows == 4:
        d16 = ['RU19-24', 'RU13-18', 'RU7-12', 'RU1-6']
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((N_rows, N_cols)), index=d16 ,columns=names_df)
    else:
        print("The Elevation for each domain is defined by 4, you defined elevation: ", N_rows)
        df = None
        # df.loc[[],'Z'] = 3

    return tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')


a = generate_data(4,2, ['A', 'B'])
print(a)
```

Out:

> ```
> +---------+-----+-----+
> |         |   A |   B |
> |---------+-----+-----|
> | RU19-24 |   0 |   0 |
> | RU13-18 |   0 |   0 |
> | RU7-12  |   0 |   0 |
> | RU1-6   |   0 |   0 |
> +---------+-----+-----+
> ```

```
Is it possible to take the index and concatenate with the column names to get the following output ? 
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|         |           A |   B         |
|---------+-------------+-------------|
| RU19-24 |   A_RU19-24 |   B_RU19-24 |
| RU13-18 |   A_RU13-18 |   B_RU13-18 |
| RU7-12  |   A_RU7-12  |   B_RU7-12  |
| RU1-6   |   A_RU1-6   |   B_RU1-6   |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: To clarify, you are not using the numeric values in the initial table at all, right? You just want to overwrite each element of each row with a string, one unique string per row?

Comment: There is a lot going on, your question makes little sense unless you squint at it, and the title and requirements are so specific that it is hard to distill this question into a singular canonical concept that can be useful to future readers.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler, the numbers are just an order on how are getting referenced to the elev_RU dictionary, the tables I listed to show how does get concatenated and first table/figure does have the color codes as reference where comes from ...

Comment: @cs95 Sorry for the issues, I made modifications and will redo the referenced tables if is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use, `apply` which take each column of the dataframe as a pd.Series, with an index (the dataframe index) and a series name(the dataframe column header):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['RU19-24','RU13-18','RU7-12','RU1-6'], columns = ['A','B'])

df.apply(lambda x: x.name+'_'+x.index)
```

Output:

```
                 A          B
RU19-24  A_RU19-24  B_RU19-24
RU13-18  A_RU13-18  B_RU13-18
RU7-12    A_RU7-12   B_RU7-12
RU1-6      A_RU1-6    B_RU1-6
```

or use `np.add.outer`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['RU19-24','RU13-18','RU7-12','RU1-6'], columns = ['A','B'])
df_out = pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(df.columns+'_',df.index).T, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
df_out
```

Output:

```
                 A          B
RU19-24  A_RU19-24  B_RU19-24
RU13-18  A_RU13-18  B_RU13-18
RU7-12    A_RU7-12   B_RU7-12
RU1-6      A_RU1-6    B_RU1-6
```

Comment: np.add.outer approach is at least half the runtime and on large dataframes or matrix is ~50 times faster ... can you please provide simple explanation of why "ufuncs" is so powerful ? Does look for me that can be used to optimize a lot of matrix operations in a big data environment and want to know what is the "resources" used to have this huge speed improvement ...

Comment: @n1tk... I am sorry, I can't explain anymore than saying that pandas uses numpy.  And, there is a lot of overhead using pandas, if you can use numpy to do the same task, numpy will be faster.  And, maybe this could be optimized even further using different numpy techniques.